# irb/console reload! not reloading Rails observers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, reload, observers

I have an observer, which raises an error:

```
def before_create(user)
  raise "boom!"
end
```

Now, that will error out fine in the console:

```
>  u = User.create!(:email => "test@test.com", :password => "test")
RuntimeError: boom!
    /app/observers/user_observer.rb:3:in `before_create'
```

If I hit reload, the error persists:

```
>  u = User.create!(:email => "test@test.com", :password => "test")
RuntimeError: boom!
    /app/observers/user_observer.rb:3:in `before_create'
```

But if I exit and restart the rails console, it goes away.  Why? Shouldn't reload take in these observer changes?

Answer (score 3):

The Rails console does not 'reload' instantiated objects. You will need to change the instance of whatever object is raising `boom!` for any change to take affect after doing a call to `reload!`.

**Update (2)**

Here is a second update. This is more clear hopefully.

Try this:

```
# app/models/User.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # before_validation :boom

  def boom
    raise 'boom!'
  end
end
```

Then, in the console:

```
u = User.new
u.valid?
=> true
```

Then, modify your controller like so to uncomment the before_validation hook:

```
# app/models/User.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :boom

  def boom
    raise 'boom!'
  end
end
```

Then, in the console:

```
u.valid? # no crash!
=> true

u = User.new
u.valid? # no crash still!
=> true

reload!

u = User.new
u.valid? # crash!
RuntimeError: bang!
```

The key is that you `reload!` and then you re-instantiate whatever User model you were referencing. You can also re-instantiate models from the database by using ActiveRecord finders, etc. In that case, you will want to reload the column information with `User.reset_column_information`.

**References**

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/reset_column_information

Comment: updated.  Using `User.create` to create a new object every time.

Comment: Note that the actual `User` class has to be changed (re-loaded) in order for it to change the behavior in `create!`, even after you call `reload!`.

Comment: OK, just tested.  It appears to have just reset the column information, the observer did not reload..

Comment: How does instantiating the User object reload the Observer? I am running into this same problem. `load 'app/models/user_observer.rb'` returns true but does not reload the file...